# Typecasting WideString breaks array of widechar

Tags: delphi-7, delphi

I use this procedure to ENUM the keys into a TNTListView (UNICODE) in Delphi 7

```
procedure TForm1.TntButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 k        : HKEY;
 Buffer   : array of widechar;
 i        : Integer;
 iRes     : Integer;
 BuffSize : DWORD;
 item     : TTNTListItem;
 WS       : WideString;
begin
 if RegOpenKeyExW (HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software', 0, KEY_READ, K) = ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
  try
    i := 0;
    BuffSize := 1;
    while true do begin
      SetLength (Buffer, BuffSize);
      iRes := RegEnumKeyW(k, I, @Buffer[0], BuffSize);
      if iRes = 259 then break;
      if iRes = 234 then begin
        inc (BuffSize);
        continue;
      end;
      messageboxw (0, @Buffer[0], '', 0);
      item := TNTListView1.Items.Add;
      item.Caption := WideString (Buffer); // BREAKS IT
      { SOLUTION }
      SetLength (WS, BuffSize - 1);
      CopyMemory (@WS[1], @Buffer[0], (BuffSize * 2));
      { .... }
      inc (i);
      BuffSize := 1;
    end;
  finally
    RegCloseKey (k);
    SetLength (Buffer, 0);
  end;
 end;
end;
```

I see that most of the listviewitems are trimmed! However if I show the Buffer in the messagebox it shows the complete string in the right length. Is this a Bug of the listview or am I missing something like a NULL CHAR (or even 2)?

Thanks for help.

EDIT: I just noticed that the Buffer get's trimmed into half when I cast it to a widestring.

EDIT2: No bug in the listview. The WideString Cast breaks the string somehow and / or doesn't detect the NULL CHAR(s).

Comment: I believe there is a maxlength property.

Comment: `(BuffSize * 2)`  -> `(BuffSize * SizeOf(WideChar))` or `(BuffSize * SizeOf(@Buffer[0]))`.

Comment: WideString is a warpper around Microsoft COM/OLE BSTR type. It is probably zero-ended like opther C-strings.

Comment: It is zero ended. I just don't know if you need two NULLCHARS at the  end (because of UNICODE) or just one.

Comment: You need only one null character at the end, just like any other string. The character is two bytes wide, but it's stool just one character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right - casting `array of WideChar` to `WideString` halves the string length in pre-Unicode Delphi's.

Tested on Delphi 2007:

```
var
  A: array of WideChar;

begin
  SetLength(A, 4);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(WideString(A)))); // 2
end;
```

---

A quick view on the above code in debugger CPU window shows that typecasting `array of WideChar`-> `WideString` does not result in any data conversion; [internal WideString format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) stores the string **size** (i.e. the number of bytes) in the same place where Delphi strings or dynarrays store **length**. As a result typecasting halves string length.

Comment: what would do ShowMessage(IntToStr(Length(WideString(PWidechar(A))))); ?

Comment: Shows string length - what else? if you mean you get just a zero-terminated PWideChar after cast - no, WideString has a length field like a Delphi string

Comment: which ? 2 or 4 ? does PWideChar intermediate typecast fix division or not ?

Comment: SetLength(A, 4); allocates 4 times the size of a widechar ( 4 x 2 bytes) which comes to a total of 8 bytes but in StringFormat it's only 4 printable UNICODE chars.

Comment: If the RTL really is this buggy,, then use `SetString()` instead to copy the array into the `WideString`, eg: `var W: WideString; SetString(W, @A[0], Length(A));`

Comment: Delphi 7 does not support WideStrings with SetString